# Что вернуть, если ничего не надо? Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть обработчик. Я получаю данные, сохраняю их, а что вернуть? Как будет правильнее? Может просто пустой HttpResponse, или что?

views.py

```py
def add_mail_to_subscriptions(request):
    body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    email = json.loads(body)['email']
    user = SubscribedEmail.objects.filter(email=email)
    if not user.exists():
        SubscribedEmail.objects.create(email=email)
```

Comment: возвращайте 200 код или 500 (если не получилось).

Comment: А где именно это передать? Как функция называется?

Comment: я не специалист в джанго.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ. Поищу информацию

Comment: Хотя бы сообщение "success" отправьте что ли, а то совсем пустой HttpResponse будет вызывать некоторое недоумение

Comment: @andreymal правильный http код сам за себя говорит, ничего дополнительно возвращать не нужно

Comment: @KoVadim 500 - это совсем неожиданная ошибка, для более специфических есть свои коды. Например, не все параметры передали - 400, несуществующий ресурс - 404 и т.д.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA а ещё он может говорить о том, что между отправкой кода и отправкой тела ответа произошла какая-то ошибка, о которой клиент не может узнать, потому что код уже успел отправиться перед появлением ошибки

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA я знаю http коды.  Но вот 202 отправлять - я даже не знаю, кто это обычно делает. Обычно отправляют 200/404/500 и все. Ну может ещё 451.

Comment: @andreymal Это совсем не аргумент, а даже наоборот. Так как ошибка может произойти в любой момент, и в момент передачи тела тоже, то нужно знать смог ли сервер сделать то, что его просили, безотносительно проблем с передачей ответа. Для этого и нужен код, который передается в заголовках до передачи тела. Чтоб клиент знал все ли дошло сервер передает заголовок content-length. Если не все дошло, то узнать это из-за ошибки сети или сервер накрылся в середине обработки в принципе нельзя.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA в принципе можно, если внутри самого́ тела есть какое-то обозначение его завершения (например, закрывающие фигурные скобки в json-ответе). Повторюсь, пустое тело будет вызывать недоумение, а какое-нибудь `{"success": true}`, успешно полученное полностью, будет давать хотя бы какую-то надежду, что всё действительно success

Comment: @andreymal Я вас не понимаю. Если ответ слать клиенту до того, как мы делаем собственно обработку, то какая разница это будет код в заголовках или в теле? В любом случае мы получим ответ, который ничего не гарантирует. Если же, как полагается, мы ответ шлем после, то разницы нет, код правильный - значит все сделали. Зачем слать дополнительные данные? И я пишу, "если не дошло". В этом случае как это поможет? Клиент будет только знать, что он не получил ответ и все.

Comment: @KoVadim У меня другой опыт. 202 - обычное дело, когда отправляем запрос на асинхронную обработку, т.е. результат проверяем потом, дополнительными вызовами. 400 - постоянно, если не все параметры передали или форматы неправильные. 500 - это catch all для любого необработанной ошибки, если ошибка понятна, то лучше специфический код.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA а я не понимаю, почему вы так не любите непустые ответы, если они никому хуже не делают

Comment: а код 200 - это пустой ответ?

Comment: @andreymal я не люблю дублировать. Есть стандартный способ передачи статуса. Зачем еще передавать что-то? И трафика больше, и что клиенту делать если пришли несогласованные данные в статусе и в теле? А от вас готов услышать ответ по существу на вопрос из предыдущего комментария, так как еще раз повторюсь: я не понимаю как ваше предложение решает ту проблему, которую вы заявили.

Comment: @KoVadim - нет. 204 явно говорит, что тело пустое. 200 означает просто "все в порядке, в теле может что-то быть", клиенту нужно смотреть content-length, если он есть, если нет, то конец тела это когда сервер закрывает соединение.

Comment: а у меня не в этом был вопрос и он был к andreymal. Суть в том, что если я послал послал в заголовках код 200, то это пустой ответ или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно вернуть HTTP status в ответе

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def add_mail_to_subscriptions(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Какой именно зависит от того, как вы проектируете API. В вашем случае, похоже, правильно будет 204 или 200.

Вот цитата с сокращениями из [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%85):

> - 200 OK — успешный запрос. Если клиентом были запрошены какие-либо данные, то они находятся в заголовке и/или теле сообщения.
> - 201 Created — в результате успешного выполнения запроса был создан новый ресурс. При обработке запроса новый ресурс должен быть создан до отправки ответа клиенту, иначе следует использовать ответ с кодом 202.
> - 202 Accepted — запрос был принят на обработку, но она не завершена. Клиенту не обязательно дожидаться окончательной передачи сообщения, так как может быть начат очень долгий процесс.
> - 204 No Content — сервер успешно обработал запрос, но в ответе были переданы только заголовки без тела сообщения.